# Leaflet map: how to removeLayer and add popups to the map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I'm trying to `addLayer` (**marker, circle and popup**) to the map.

I am able to add the marker and circle successfully but I cannot add the popup and also I cannot removeLayer which result in multiplying the marker and circle...

It basically doesn't remove the previous marker and circle before adding the new one in.

This is a working FIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/31ws6z37/3/

And this is my entire code:

```
         function initializeMapAndLocator(){

                var map = L.map('map_2385853');




    googleStreets = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
}).addTo(map);



           map.locate({setView: true, 
                       maxZoom: 16, 
                       watch:true, 
                       timeout: 60000
                      });

      function onLocationFound(e) {
        var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
        var marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng, {draggable:true});
        var circles = new L.circle(e.latlng, radius).bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();;

        map.removeLayer(marker);
        map.removeLayer(circles);




        map.addLayer(marker);
        map.addLayer(circles);







      }

      map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);



         }

initializeMapAndLocator();
```

Could someone please let me know how to removeLayer and also how to add the popup to my map?

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Nothing seems to be working and I'm pulling hair out. Every corner I turned and every search indicates that I need to use the removeLayer to remove the marker but this is not the case for me and I don't understand it!!

This is another version of my code and still adds markers before removing the old one....

```
var map = L.map('map_2385853');

    googleStreets = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
}).addTo(map);



           map.locate({setView: true, 
                       maxZoom: 16, 
                       watch:true, 
                       timeout: 60000
                      });

      function onLocationFound(e) {
        var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
        var marker;
        var circles;


        marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng, {draggable:true});
        circles = new L.circle(e.latlng, radius);


        //var pop = new bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

        map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        map.removeLayer(marker);
        map.removeLayer(circles);
       });


     map.addLayer(marker);
     map.addLayer(circles);

      }

      map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I just don't know where and how!

Any help would be great.

Comment: oke I will look whats going wrong

Comment: Is that what you want?

Comment: @Manuel, you are my hero mate. Believe it or not, I was reading the doc's and came close to your solution but I didn't use haslayer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you a mixing the wrong stuff together. It would be easier for you to learn the [basics](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) creating a leaflet map. In your first snippet you first initialize the marker, then remove it and the you add it to your map. That make no sense and isn't logical. Ask in the `onLocationFound()` function if the marker and circles layers are on the map. If true then remove it:

```
  var marker; 
  var circles;

  function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

    if(map.hasLayer(circles) && map.hasLayer(marker)) {
        map.removeLayer(circles);
      map.removeLayer(marker);
    } 

            marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng, {draggable:true});
            circles = new L.circle(e.latlng, radius);
        circles.bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

            map.addLayer(marker);
    map.addLayer(circles);

}
```

Here is a the modified **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/31ws6z37/5/)**. Hope it helps

greez Manuel